# Azure pipeline build iOS using ionic

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a pipeline for my ionic project. I've been struggling with this for the past week. I'm using a pipeline for each Android and iOS, the former is working fine.

**iOS YAML**

```
variables:
  scheme: "App"
  sdk: "iphoneos"
  configuration: "Release"

pool:
  vmImage: "macOS-latest"

steps:
  - task: Npm@1 # Run npm install
    inputs:
      command: install
      workingDir: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: custom
      customCommand: run build

  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: "specific"
      project: "a3706115-71e0-4d2c-a224-5eb27f5d6aed"
      definition: "5"
      buildVersionToDownload: "latest"
      targetPath: "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"

  - bash: |
      sudo npm i -g @ionic/cli

  - bash: |
      npx ionic cap add ios

  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: '$(p12FileName)'
      certPwd: '$(p12Password)'
      keychain: 'temp'
      deleteCert: true

  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: '$(provisioningProfile)'
      removeProfile: true

  - task: CocoaPods@0
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ios/App'
      forceRepoUpdate: false

  - task: Xcode@5
    inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: '$(configuration)'
      sdk: '$(sdk)'
      xcWorkspacePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ios/App/App.xcworkspace'
      scheme: '$(scheme)'
      packageApp: true
      archivePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      signingOption: 'manual'
      signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
      provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
      args: 'CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: '**/*.ipa'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      overWrite: true

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/$(configuration)'
      artifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

receiving the below error:

```
error: exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive.
Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 70
```

I don't have a mac to test the ionic xcode locally.

Anyone have an idea why this issue is happening?

Comment: Ypu can have a try setting `exportOptions` to `specify` and specified `exportMethod` as app-store and adding the Team ID to `teamId` for Xcode task.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in your build.json file

```json
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO"
      ],
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXX",
      "automaticProvisioning": true,
      "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO"
      ],
      "codeSignIdentity": "Apple Development",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXX",
      "automaticProvisioning": true,
      "packageType": "app-store"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install certificates and provisioning profile**

To sign your application you will need to install the certificate and provisioning profile that we have already imported into the Azure dashboard as a [Secure-Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)